# how to update struct fields?

Tags: matlab

I have a structure e.g. `struct.a = {zeros(4)}`. Now I want to update the first row of `a` with `[4 4 4 4]`. How to access the first row from the `struct.a` and update it? The result should be the matrix with `cell2mat(struct.a(1)) = [4 4 4 4;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly braces and regular braces together:

```
>> struct.a = {zeros(4)}
struct = 
    a: {[4x4 double]}
>> struct.a{1}(1,:) = [4 4 4 4]; % or just assign a scalar (e.g. = 4;)
>> struct.a{1}
ans =
     4     4     4     4
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

By the way, you don't need to store a cell in `struct.a`.  This is fine too:

```
struct.a = zeros(4);
struct.a(1,:) = 4;
```

Also, importantly, do NOT use `struct` as a variable name since it is a keyword in MATLAB.